# Form not being submitted with correct data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, smarty

I have a form for a quiz that has 3 different inputs. Number of questions, and two types of tests.  i am modifying existing code that works fine but we want the layout different which requires it to be coded differently. this is the version that isn't working. Basically I need the number of questions and category to be sent with the button clicked.  For some reason it isn't sending either. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
        <strong>Questions</strong>
                <select name="num_questions">
                {section name=foo start=10 loop=31} 
                <option value={$smarty.section.foo.index}>{$smarty.section.foo.index}</option>
                {/section}
                </select>

            </div>  
            <select onchange="$('.questions_{$c.categorynum}').val(this.value);" name="category">
            {foreach from=$categories item=c}
                {if ($c.categorynum != 1 and $c.categorynum < 8)}
                <div class="questiontitle" style="float:left;">
                <option value={$c.categorynum}><strong>{$c.name}</strong></option>
                </div>
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
            </select>

            <form action="test.php" method="post" style="float:left;">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Exam" name="create" style="margin:0 3px;"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="category" class="category" value="{$c.categorynum}"/>
                <input type="hidden" class="questions_{$c.categorynum}" name="num_questions" value="10"/>
            </form>
            <form action="simulation.php" method="post" style="float:left;">
                <input type="submit" name="flashcard" value="Flash Cards" style="margin:0 3px;"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="create" value="1"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="category" value="{$c.categorynum}"/>
                <input type="hidden" class="questions_{$c.categorynum}" name="numquestions" value="10"/>
            </form>
```

Comment: You should move num_questions and category inside tag form. If you dont like this you can add hidden field and use onchange event to set hidden value

Comment: can you give an example? it sounds like that is already how it is set up...

Comment: Which POST values did you receive in your php ?